# Git push full project, pull only distribution files

Tags: git

I have a big (to me) project with lots of files that are just used for development - for example, the full Bootstrap 4 source code.  I use that source code to generate `bootstrap.css` and `style.css`.

I'd like to keep everything on my dev box and in the repository. but when I'm deploying to production, I don't need all those build `.scss` files, just the resulting `.css`.  Is there a way to do that?  A sort of `.gitignore` I can use when deploying to production, but ignore when merging from dev to git?

I'm only really interested if Git has this type of functionality built-in.  This is a "like to do" not a "must do at any cost".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't really recommend using git as a deployment tool, if it's what you're going to do then sparse checkout is probably the easiest way to get git to do what you want.

(Using a build tool to explicitly construct a deployment package is a far more flexible solution that's less likely to bite you in the rear later.  I see where you've written that it's not what you want to do, but if I'm leaving this answer I'm including this caveat so you can't say I didn't warn you.)

Comment: sparse checkout looks like it'll do what I asked.  And your caveat is duly noted ;)  Admittedly I've never used build tools in this manner, or at all really.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Build tool recommendations would depend on the project. It looks like you're dealing with a (mostly?) client-side app? I like gulp; some people prefer grunt. Note that these don't strictly speaking address the actual deployment; rather they help with assembling a deployable package - e.g. by copying just the needed files into a structure ready to deploy, in this case. So this approach leads toward using more tools, but each is focused on / good at what it does. Then if you later need more complicated transformations from code to deployable - minify, bundle, whatever - the tools are ready